# Getting wrong data while reading wsdl dynamically

Tags: wcf, wsdl

This is my WCF WSDL file.

```
<wsdl:portType name="IMyService">
  <wsdl:operation name="add">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://pcname:9000/WcfService/MyService/IMyService/add"
                message="tns:IMyService_add_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://pcname:9000/WcfService/MyService/IMyService/addResponse" 
                 message="tns:IMyService_add_OutputMessage"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
  <wsdl:operation name="sub">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://pcname:9000/WcfService/MyService/IMyService/sub"
                message="tns:IMyService_sub_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://pcname:9000/WcfService/MyService/IMyService/subResponse" 
                 message="tns:IMyService_sub_OutputMessage"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

I am trying to dynamically add reference to my project.

While reading WSDL dynamically I am getting an exception

Line in code:

```
ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);
```

Error:

> Exception: Unable to import binding 'BasicHttpBinding_IMyService' from namespace http:// pcname:9000/WcfService/MyService/.
>
> Inner excepetion : {"The element 'http:// pcname:9000/WcfService/MyService/:add' is missing."}

Why am I getting ":" (colon) before "add" function?

Comment: Why is there a space inside `http:// pcname`?

Comment: it is localhost in actual code. i am new to stack overflow while posting question it is giving me some error regarding that link, so i changed it to pcname.